# How to generate light weight videos with ffmpeg for Power Point in OS X?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, powerpoint

I want to make some movies with ffmpeg to use them on a Powerpoint in Mac OS X. I am using this command, which works well but generates large movies (about 100 MB) without losing too much quality.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 100 -pattern_type glob -i 'img*.png' -c:v mjpeg -qscale:v 20 test.avi
```

I have also tried using other codecs like mpeg4 and libx264 to generate lighter movies (about 10 MB) but they don't work correctly in the Powerpoint presentation.

Does anyone know how to use them correctly or how to create a light weight movie with ffmpeg that works well on Powerpoint for OS X?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?